# MYSQL return two table separately after JOIN and WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables programs(uuid, school_id, attribute...) and schools(uuid, school_type_id), programs.school_id is foreign key to schools.uuid.

Now in db I have, for example, 1 school and 2 programs that belong to that school.

I need api response to do filter with condition (attribute) and return the filtered programs and schools separately. But I can't avoid the duplicate school rows.

```
SELECT 
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'programs', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'uuid', p.uuid
        )
      ),
      'schools', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'uuid', s.uuid,
          'school_name_en', s.school_name_en
        ) 
      )
    ) as result 
FROM program_info p
INNER JOIN schools s
ON p.school_id = s.uuid
WHERE p.uuid IN (p_uuid1, p_uuid2)
AND s.school_type_id = 2
```

in response the schools array contain duplicate as the two programs belong to the same school

```
{
    "schools": [
        {
            "uuid": "2cf1b623-3f83-487f-b642-699edda596d1",
            "school_name_en": "ut3"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "2cf1b623-3f83-487f-b642-699edda596d1",
            "school_name_en": "ut3"
        }
    ],
    "programs": [
        {
            "uuid": "726a5328-f68a-4870-9532-04582535b000"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "b180d891-25fd-49fa-bdab-b728421abfb8"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I return the filtered school list without duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table u (uid int, uName varchar(100));
Create table p (pid int, uid int, pName varchar(100));
insert into u select 1, 'UoT';
insert into u select 2, 'UoW';

insert into p select 1, 1, 'Y1 Computer uoT';
insert into p select 2, 1, 'Y2 Math uoT';
insert into p select 3, 1, 'Y2 Art uoT';
insert into p select 4, 2, 'Y2 Engineer uoW';
insert into p select 5, 2, 'Y2 Math uoW';
insert into p select 6, 2, 'Y1 Art uoW';

select concat(
'{ "schools":  [' , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(json_object("uid", u.uid, "uName", uName ))), '],',
' "programs": [' , GROUP_CONCAT(json_object("uid", p.uid, "pName", pName )), ']}'
) 
from U join p on u.UID =p.UID where uName like '%W%' and pName like '%Y2%';
```

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB, you can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT ...)`; it seems that MySQL currently doesn't allow that: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91993.